# Bundle item quantity sets to 1

Tags: bundle

I am having two bundle items each defined separately as a radio button. And the quantity of both can be determined by the user. But, if the quantity of the bundle item is set to zero and the user clicks "Add to cart" button. In the cart the bundle item's quantity which was set to zero is automatically set to 1. I have set the minimum quantity for cart to 0 in inventory. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done by being able to setting "is required" property of the radio items to No. The user can click None or set a quantity. If he selects None, then the item quantity would not increase to 1 upon adding to cart.